# Package dependencies for a self-created package

Tags: r, package

This question is regarding self-created R packages(on ubuntu 16.04) , the package dependencies mentioned in imports are not getting installed .The solution presented on online sources is to , create a repo with all the packages and then make the self-created package download the dependencies from there. I wanted my package to install the dependent packages from CRAN and not from an online repo. Please have a look at the following output:----
I am using the following command to install the source package :-

```
install.packages(file.choose(),repos = NULL ,type="source")
```

The following error shows:-

```
Installing package into ‘/home/piyush96/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies ‘jsonlite’, ‘stringr’, ‘MODIStsp’, ‘sp’, ‘maptools’, ‘plyr’, ‘rgdal’ are not available for package ‘ModisLST’
* removing ‘/home/piyush96/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ModisLST’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/piyush96/Downloads/ModisLST_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The DESCRIPTION file looks like this:-

```
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Imports: jsonlite,stringr,MODIStsp,sp,maptools,plyr,foreign,rgdal
Suggests: knitr, rmarkdown
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Built: R 3.4.3; ; 2018-01-02 12:44:23 UTC; unix
```

How do I make R download all the dependencies by itself from CRAN without making a repo or using devtools?

Comment: "`dependencies` - logical indicating whether to also install uninstalled packages which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest (and so on recursively). Not used if `repos = NULL`." The documentation seems clear.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for replying.              install.packages(file.choose(), type="source",dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/piyush96/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)        
Warning in install.packages :
                          package ‘/home/piyush96/Downloads/ModisLST_0.1.0.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)                                                                                                                    
                        library(ModisLST)
Error in library(ModisLST) : there is no package called ‘ModisLST’

Comment: The issue that I'm facing is that, on making making dependencies  =TRUE, Rstudio shows an error saying ," no such package"

Comment: You don't seem to understand that dependencies can only be installed if you install a package from a repository. That's what the documentation indicates.

Comment: Oh..  got it. Thanks a lot Roland.